# Plotly Dash: Left padding for dcc.Upload component

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I'm building a web application using Dash. I want to give the user the ability to upload a file using the `dcc.Upload` component.

My code for that piece is as follows:

```
html.Div([
    dcc.Upload(
        id='upload-data',
        children=html.Div([
            'Drag and Drop or ',
            html.A('Select Files')
        ]),
        style={
        'margin-left' : '300px',
        'width' : '50%',
        'height' : '60px',
        'lineHeight' : '60px',
        'borderWidth' : '1px',
        'borderStyle' : 'dashed',
        'borderRadius' : '5px',
        'textAlign' : 'center',
        'margin' : '10px'
        },
        multiple=True
        ),
    html.Div(id='output-data-upload'),
    ]),
```

I'm trying to give some left padding on the box that displays "Drag and Drop or Select Files".

In the `style` dictionary, the `'margin-left' : '300px'` seems to have no effect.

I also tried `marginLeft`, which doesn’t work either.

What is the correct way to give left padding on the `dcc.Upload` component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that `'margin-left': '300px'` is overwritten by `'margin': '10px'`, which is why you see no effect. Note that you can specify all margins at once. For instance, setting `'margin': '10px 5px 3px 300px'` will add a 10px top margin, a 5px right margin, a 3px bottom margin and a 300px left margin.